# For different value of input module is giving same result

Tags: functions, function-construction, scoping

I have a simple module written to extract a certain shape for a certain value of ω, but I am getting the same result for different input values into the module.
1.mode[1] and mode[2] looks exactly same 
2.mode[2] and mode[2]  looks exactly the same but looks different from the previous set. 
How to overcome this?

```
γ = 1;
fixedfreee = Table[Sin[((2*i + 1)*π*x2)/(2*γ)], {i, 0, 2}];
barmodes = Flatten[{fixedfreee}];
Table[Plot[barmodes[[i]], {x2, 0, γ}], {i, 1, 
   Length[barmodes]}];
U = Expand[Total[Table[d[i]*barmodes[[i]], {i, 1, Length[barmodes]}]]];
Ux = Expand[D[U, {x2, 1}]];
in3 = Expand[(Ux)^2];
in4 = Expand[(U)^2];
var2 = Table[d[i], {i, 1, Length[barmodes]}];

v2 = 0.5*Integrate[in3, {x2, 0, 1}];

t2 = 0.5*ω^2 Integrate[in4, {x2, 0, 1}];

T = t2;
V = v2;
Lg = (T - V);
variables = Flatten[{var2}];
equations = 
 Table[D[Lg, {variables[[i]], 1}], {i, 1, Length[variables]}]; Rarz = 
 Normal@CoefficientArrays[equations, variables][[2]]; 
MatrixForm[Rarz];
P = FullSimplify[Numerator[Det[Rarz]]];
Plot[P, {ω, 0, 2000}];
s1 = NSolve[P == 0 && 0 < ω < 4000];
s2 = (ω /. s1);

 modes[j_] := 
 Module[{mm}, {uu, ww, vv} = 
   SingularValueDecomposition[Rarz /. ω -> s2[[j]]]; 
  nn = Last[Transpose[vv]]; 
  U = (U /. Table[var2[[i]] -> nn[[i]], {i, 1, Length[var2]}]); 
  mm = U;  Return[mm]]

m1 = modes[1]
m2 = modes[2]
p1 = Plot[m1, {x2, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.007]}];
p2 = Plot[m2, {x2, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.007]}];
Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition of `modes`, you set a new value for `U` here:

```
U = (U /. Table[var2[[i]] -> nn[[i]], {i, 1, Length[var2]}]);
```

Any subsequent calls to mode will simply return this value. Try instead

```
modes[j_] := Module[{nn},
  nn = Last[
    Transpose[
     Last[SingularValueDecomposition[Rarz /. \[Omega] -> s2[[j]]]]]];
  U /. Thread[var2 -> nn]
  ]
```

A separate call to `Return` is not needed because `Module` will automatically return the last expression in its body.

Does this do what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for, but if I want multiple out put then how to return them?

Comment: @acoustics Do you mean something like this: `Plot[modes /@ Range[3], {x2, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.007]}]`? Here `/@` maps `modes` over a list of arguments given by `Range[3]`. Take a look also at `Listable`.

Comment: No, what I asked is  suppose if I CONSTRUCT A FUNCTION using the module , and it  has two outputs, how to return them

Comment: @acoustics Just put the outputs in a list `{output1,output2,...}` and return that. 

By the way, just a friendly tip. People will feel more inclined to help you if you are polite and refrain from things like using all caps.

Comment: Actually I thought you did not understood the question properly, that is why I made it bold. Your is suggestion is welcomed. Thanks